# Is it possible to do a post on the Facebook user's wall and did not authorize, in each case?

Tags: java, android, facebook, facebook-wall

Actually I have a problem - I did login to Facebook in my application. I can also do wall posts authorized by the user, but that I needed each time to call the authorization - it takes some time and leads to the fact that on the screen (for a short time), there is "the box" with a white background ( https://dl.dropbox.com/u/41114685/1.JPG ) that is generated (induced) Facebook. That's why I'm interested in whether it is possible to do a post on the user's wall does not cause, each time a method for authentication (to make posts out method onComplete())?
 I hope for your help.

```
package expir.java.file;

import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;

import com.facebook.android.DialogError;
import com.facebook.android.Facebook;
import com.facebook.android.Facebook.DialogListener;
import com.facebook.android.FacebookError;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;

public class FacebookAuthorizeAndPost implements DialogListener{

FacebookAuthorizeAndPost(Activity activity){
    this.activity = activity;
}

public void facebookAuthorize(){
    facebookClient = new Facebook(APP_ID);
    facebookClient.authorize(activity, new String[]{"publish_stream"}, Facebook.FORCE_DIALOG_AUTH, this);
}

public void onComplete(Bundle values) {
    if (values.isEmpty())
    {
        return;
    }
    if (!values.containsKey("post_id"))
    {
        try
        {
            Bundle cont = new Bundle();
            cont.putString("message", "bla-bla-bla");
            cont.putString("name", "Testing facebook");
            cont.putString("link", "www.????????.com");
            cont.putString("description", "This is a funny real test!!! This is a funny real test!!! This is a funny real test!!! This is a funny real test!!!");
            cont.putString("picture", "http://code.google.com/p/android-developer-scripts/logo?cct=1294556390");
            //facebookClient.dialog(activity, "feed", cont, this);
            facebookClient.request("me/feed", cont, "POST");
        }   
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    } 
}

public void onFacebookError(FacebookError e) {
    //
}

public void onError(DialogError e) {
    // 
}

public void onCancel() {
    // 
}

public Activity activity;   
private final String APP_ID = "??????????????????";
private Facebook facebookClient;

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `isSessionValid()` method of `Facebook` class to check if a valid non-expired session exists, if it doesn't then call the `authorize()` method otherwise proceed with posting on user's wall.

Also please refer to this post here: http://blog.doityourselfandroid.com/2011/02/28/30-minute-guide-integrating-facebook-android-application/

Comment: you can explain why need include SessionEvents.AuthListener ?

Comment: this is well explained in the tutorial "An imporant thing to note is that when the user clicks the Post Message button, besides logging just logging in, we also want to send the message to the Facebook wall. Performing the login, immediately followed by an action (in this case sending a message) can be done by adding a AuthenticationListener (SessionEvents.AuthListener) to the SessionEvents." - So basically it is used to hook the listener to auth event and once authenticated proceed with posting on wall

Answer (score 0):

I have just posted an example of this on another question a couple of mins ago.

See here - [logging into facebook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12597094/how-to-log-in-to-facebook-on-android/12597617#12597617)